How to extend the boundary of polygon until a line?
I have two objects:
eez:https://github.com/yuliaUU/test/blob/main/eez.RDS
bordering_polygons: https://github.com/yuliaUU/test/blob/main/madg_bordering_polygons.RData
So what I want to do is to try to extend the outer boundary of each bordering_polygons untill eez line, and so that boundaries will not overlap
As suggested , i tried teh following:
v <- vect(bordering_polygons)
r <- rast(eez, res=.1)
# get the distance to each polygon, and then find the nearest polygon
rr <- lapply(1:nrow(v), \(i) distance(r, v[i])) |> rast() |> which.min()

z <- erase(as.polygons(rr), v)
values(z) <- values(v)[unlist(z[[1]]),  ]
x <- rbind(v, z)
a <- aggregate(x, names(x))
plot(v)
plot(a, "ADM1_EN", type="classes")
lines(v, lwd=3, col="gray")
lines(eez, col="red", lwd=3)


my only issue that the created areas are not combined with existing polygons

Alternatively, calculate the intersection point of each polygon edge with the various "likely" segments of your eez polygon.  Then extend said edges to that point and redefine each polygon accordingly.

The tricky bit is to extend polygons. Here is an approach that uses a (discrete) raster.
Example data (please do not ask questions based on files that need to be downloaded)
library(terra)
# your island 
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
# use planar crs to speed things up
vcrs <- crs(v)
crs(v) <- "local"
# example EEZ
e <- as.polygons(ext(v) + .05, crs=crs(v)) 

Define a raster (higher resolution is better, but slower)
r <- rast(e, res=.01)
# get the distance to each polygon, and then find the nearest polygon
rr <- lapply(1:nrow(v), \(i) distance(r, v[i])) |> rast() |> which.min()

Create polygons, erase what we already have, set the attributes and combine with the admin areas of the island.
z <- erase(as.polygons(rr), v)
values(z) <- values(v)[unlist(z[[1]]),  ]
x <- rbind(v, z)
a <- aggregate(x, names(x))
crs(a) <- vcrs

Illustration of the result
plot(a, "ID_2", type="classes")
lines(v, lwd=3, col="gray")
lines(e, col="red", lwd=3)


For your data you need some minor adjustments (because the island has a hole and the outside boundary is not rectangular.
eez <- vect(eez)
mdg <- vect(bordering_polygons)
mcrs <- crs(mdg)
crs(eez) <- crs(mdg) <- "local"

r <- rast(eez, res=.1)
rr <- lapply(1:nrow(mdg), \(i) distance(r, mdg[i])) |> rast() |> which.min()

fmdg <- aggregate(mdg) |> fillHoles()
z <- erase(as.polygons(rr), fmdg)
values(eez) <- NULL
z <- intersect(z, eez)
values(z) <- values(mdg)[unlist(z[[1]]), ,drop=FALSE]
x <- rbind(mdg, z)
x <- aggregate(x, names(x))
crs(x) <- mcrs

plot(x, "ADM1_EN", type="classes")
lines(mdg, lwd=3, col="gray")
lines(eez, col="red", lwd=3)


